# date-fns/parseISO Obtener fecha correcta en caso de que no haya horas

Tags: reactjs, date-format

Tengo un problemita con esa libreria `date-fns/parseISO`, el problema es que la estoy utilizando para darle formato a las fechas y horas que lleguen de un endpoint, por ejemplo:

Si del endpoint llega ésta fecha: y hora: 2023-08-09T09:21:40

Yo estoy utilizando date-fns/parseISO para que el front me muestre la fecha y hora asi: 09/08/2023 09:21:40

ésta es la funcion que utilizo:

```
const formatDate = (
  date: any,
  ignoreHours: boolean = true,
  formatDate: string = "dd/MM/yyyy"
) => {
  if (!date || date === "") return;
  if (ignoreHours) date = new Date(date).toISOString().split("T")[0];
  
  const reg = /^\d+$/;
  const numbersOnlytest = reg.test(date);
  if (numbersOnlytest) {
    date = new Date(+date).toISOString();
  }
  return format(parseISO(date), formatDate);
};
```

Mi problema es que no siempre "date" llega con una hora, es decir, date puede ser por ejemplo 2023-08-09T00:00:00, y en ese caso el front me lo muestra de la siguiente manera: 08/08/2023 21:00:00

Como puedo hacer para que si una fecha llegue con la hora T00:00:00  solamente se muestre la hora correcta.

EJEMPLO:

**FECHA Y HORA DE ENDPOINT:** 2023-08-09T00:00:00

**ESPERADO:** 09/08/2023

**LO QUE TENGO:** 08/08/2023 21:00:00

Así es como llega del back:

```
"created_at": "2023-06-28T14:54:40.812Z"
```

Comment: Pues suena a que te está dando la hora local basado en que lo que recibes es UTC. Estás en zona horaria -3 por casualidad?

Comment: Por lo que vi, estoy en GMT-3

Comment: Se puede arreglar con i18n de casualidad? Se me acaba de ocurrir

Comment: No, las zonas horarias no tienen nada que ver con la traducción o internacionalización (i18n). Todo va a depender de lo que quieras hacer con tus casos de uso. Si la fecha la recibes ee una representación de cadena ISO con zona horaria neutra (UTC), entonces tendrás que manejarla como tal. Puedes poner un ejemplo exacto de los valores que recibes y la salida que esperas? Podría darte una respuesta, pero sin la librería que dices usar. Siempre procuro no depender de librerías de terceros para el manejo de fechas, por más cómodas que éstas parezcan. Saludos

Comment: Por otro lado, no está bien que llames a tu función `formatDate`y la misma reciba un parámetro que llamas de la misma forma: `formatDate`, en todo caso, sería `dateFormat` lo que deberías usar para diferenciarlo del nombre de la función. Porque, cuando pasas `formatDate` al método `format` ¿a quién se está refiriendo?. Es confuso.

Comment: @MauricioContreras ahi te muestro un registro de cómo llega del endpoint

Answer (score -1):

Tal como sospechaba en mis comentarios, el `backend` te está enviando la fecha y hora en fotmato ISO con zona horaria neutra ([UTC](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiempo_universal_coordinado)).

No utilizo la librería [`date-fns`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-fns), pero creo que comprendo lo que quieres.

**Usando `date-fns`**

Quieres devolver un formato específico de fecha usando esta librería, pero no has tomado en cuenta el tema de la zona horaria. Por lo cual el resultado obtenido no es el esperado.

Un cambio que haría yo, en mi función, es el tipo de comprobación a realizar sobre la cadena recibida.

Una forma de lograrlo sería la siguiente:

```js
const formatDate = (
  dateString: string,
  dateFormat: string = "dd/MM/yyyy"
): string => {
  const date = new Date(dateString);
  if(date.toString() === 'Invalid Date' || !date.valueOf()) {
    return;
  }
  return format(date, dateFormat);
}
```

De esta forma tendrás el formato que esperas. Sin embargo, como se aprecia en la función, he removido el parámetro `ignoreHours` ya que no sería correcto usarlo junto con un formato de fecha específico. Tú lo usas para mutilar la cadena recibida, seaprándola en 2 componentes usando el carácter `T` como separador. Pero luego eso lo conviertes en un objeto de fecha, que por defecto tendrá la hora en '00:00:00.000'.

Usando `new Date()`, los valores devueltos por `format` se corresponderán con la zona horaria del cliente donde se ejecuta este código. Por lo que, si estás en zona horaria GMT-3 y recibes la fecha desde el backend con una hora inferior a las 03:00:00 UTC, entonces la fecha mostrada será la del día anterior, ya que en dicha zona horaria será un día menos (realmente 3 horas menos).

Como puedes ver, esta función no tiene mucho sentido ya que al final pasa casi toda la lógica al método `format` de `date-fns`.

**Sin usar librerías**

Este es mi método favorito, ya que no dependo de librerías para hacer algo que yo mismo puedo hacer. Pero en este caso hay que crear nuestro propio `parser` del formato recibido, lo cual puede llegar a ser complicado.

Supongamos que siempre voy a mostrar la fecha recibida en el mismo formato: 'dd/mm/yyyy', entonces sería muy sencillo escribir una función que haga esto, por ejemplo:

```js
const formatDate = (dateStr) => {
  const date = new Date(dateStr);
  if(date.toString() === 'Invalid Date' || ! date.valueOf()) {
    return;
  }
  const day = date.getDate().toString().padStart(2,'0');
  const month = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0');
  const year = date.getFullYear();
  return `${day}/${month}/${year}`;
}

const dates = [
  'lol',                       // muestra: undefined
  undefined,                   // muestra: undefined
  null,                        // muestra: undefined
  '2023-06-28T14:54:40.812Z',  // muestra: 28/06/2023 ó 29/06/2023
  '2022-01-02T00:00:00.000Z',  // muestra: 02/01/2022 ó 01/01/2022
];

dates.forEach(date => console.log(formatDate(date)));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Dependiendo de tu zona horaria, la fecha mostrada para ambas fechas del Array de fechas podrían ser diferentes que las que se lee en la cadena recibida, ya que están en UTC. Así, para cualquier zona horaria negativa con respecto a UTC, la fecha mostrada para la última podría ser un día menos. Y si me encuantro en una zona horaria UTC+9 o superior a mostrada para la penúltima sería un día más.

**Edición**

Ya que comentas que deseas evitar la resta de la zona horaria, entonces no queda otra cosa que obtener los valores UTC para la fecha recibida. Para ello usaremos los métodos [`getUTC*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#date_components_and_time_zones).

Por ejemplo:

```js
const formatDate = (dateStr) => {
  const date = new Date(dateStr);
  if(date.toString() === 'Invalid Date' || ! date.valueOf()) {
    return;
  }
  const day = date.getUTCDate().toString().padStart(2,'0');
  const month = (date.getUTCMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0');
  const year = date.getUTCFullYear();
  return `${day}/${month}/${year}`;
}

const dates = [
  '2023-06-28T14:54:40.812Z',  // muestra: 28/06/2023 siempre
  '2022-01-02T00:00:00.000Z',  // muestra: 02/01/2022 siempre
];

dates.forEach(date => console.log(formatDate(date)));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Como observas, mostrará el componente día, mes y año tal como se recibe desde el `backend`, en zona neutra UTC, sin importar si el cliente está en zona negativa, positiva o cero. Para ello, uso los métodos: `getUTCDate`, `getUTCMonth` y `getUTCFullYear`.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! Me gustaria evitar la resta de 3 horas, utilizando tu funcion sin librerias, `const date = new Date(dateStr);` me está restando las horas de dateStr, sabes como evitarlo?

Comment: Por ejemplo  dateStr = `dateStr 2023-08-09T10:25:16.803Z ` y date = `date Wed Aug 09 2023 07:25:16 GMT-0300`

Comment: La resta no la puedes evitar, pero puedes mostrar la fecha que recibes de la DB, en zona horaria UTC. Ya edito la respuesta.